# how to customise error message in post request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, nestjs-swagger, nestjs-gateways

I am using nest js for making `Restfull Api` . I am also using `class-validator ,and class-transform` to validate my request ot `DTO`. Currently It is showing this error

```
{"statusCode":400,"message":["username should not be empty","description should not be empty"],"error":"Bad Request"}
```

I want to customise this response like

```
{"statusCode":400,"message":["username is required","description is required"],"error":"Bad Request from user"}
```

is it possible in `nestjs` ??

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/nest-9ziyr?file=/src/dto/user.dto.ts

I am using like that

```
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class UserDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  username: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  description: string;
}
```

**in controller**

```
 @Post('/create')
  @UsePipes(ValidationPipe)
  createUser(@Body() createTaskDto: UserDto): string {
    console.log('====');
    return 'jjjj';
  }
```

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/nest-9ziyr?file=/src/dto/user.dto.ts

**use API like that**
**POST**

```
https://9ziyr-5000.sse.codesandbox.io/create
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-messages) you can pass a message property to the validation decorator and change the error message. Something like this:

```js
import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class UserDto {
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'username is required' })
  username: string;

  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'description is required' })
  description: string;
}
```